# Using resultset in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Why can't I use a resultset as input to a stored procedure?

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

Code:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[spUpdateTrade]
     @statusID = (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[dimStatus] WHERE [name] = 'Inactive'), 
     @ID = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the result to a variable first, then you can use that:

```
DECLARE @pStatusId INT;
SELECT @pStatusId = [ID] FROM [dbo].[dimStatus] WHERE [name] = 'Inactive';
EXECUTE [dbo].[spUpdateTrade] @statusID = @pStatusId, @ID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @id int
select @id=[ID] FROM [dbo].[dimStatus] WHERE [name] = 'Inactive'--risk of getting last value in case of multiple values

EXECUTE [dbo].[spUpdateTrade]
 @statusID =@id, 
 @ID = 2
```